# HTML - Lazy load `<object>` with image data and `<img>` fallback

Tags: javascript, html, image, lazy-loading

I have a webpage that loads a dynamic grid of images all at once, and I'm wanting to set all the thumbnails to lazy load to reduce the time it takes for the page to load in. Each of these thumbnails is made using:

```
<object data="thumbnail-url">
    <img src="fallback-url" />
</object>
```

I can see from searching around online and in the MDN documentation that `<img>` tags can lazy load just by setting `<img src="" lazy />`, but I've found nothing about getting an `<object>` to lazy load.

I would like to achieve this purely with HTML if I can, but if the only way is with JavaScript then I'm alright with that as well. Any help would be appreciated!